# code not working on frmework 7 app

Tags: php, jquery, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am developing a cross platform app on framework 7 using php and mysql as back end technologies. I am retrieving data from mysql using ajax calls and this working on local server but when i put it in framework 7 its not working . Here is my code .

```
loaddata.php
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vaistra");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

$action=$_POST["action"];
if($action=="showroom"){
    $query="SELECT * FROM dirf1";
    $show=mysqli_query($link,$query) or die ("Error");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($show)){

?><tr><td><?php echo $row['dirName'] ?></td></tr><?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the jquery code

```
index.html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function showRoom(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"loaddata.php",
            data:{action:"showroom"},
            success:function(data){
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    showRoom();
});
</script>
```

here is the consol log snapshot :
[image]

So this code working fine outside framework7 but not working in framework7.
Is there anything specific should do for framework7. 
Thanks

Comment: Which part is not working? Is the request not going out to the php script, or is the php script not returning the data? Please specify you problem more!

Comment: Not showing any data in framework 7 . but when i run loaddata.php its working fine i think problem is request not going out to the php script. @FMK

Comment: Do you have any way of seeing if what the request from you jquery looks like? Maybe it is requesting the wrong url!?!

Comment: framework7 is single page application. check if ajax call is working or not. need more info to reflect the problem you are facing

Comment: URL is correct i have checked it again. @FMK

Comment: Problem is Ajax not sending request to php script . its working fine till framework 7 was not involved. @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: all scripts must be in index.php. page only.

Comment: its index.html (A html file) because php files cant run on phonegap. thats  why i'm using Ajax calls. i can't place php code in index.html. :) @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: can you add complete index.html page?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9p3nszkue1ulkt8/thanks.rar?dl=0 here is the link you can download from here .  3 files are there on is php file (loaddata.php) index.html(Framework 7 file) displaydata.html file to check it outside F7. @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: is it Framework V2

Comment: yes @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: any issue found ? @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: check for any error. in console by inspecting ajax is working fine for your code

Comment: added console image in answer please check it and help me . @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LHVzKj_aI6gz5R1mf8hn1S2KpCsqkvIx/view check this files

Comment: you need to initialize dom7 to $$ not $ to avoid js conflit. this is done in my-app.js

Comment: Need permission to access this file . requested you for access permission. Mail is er.sharmauttam@gmail.com

Comment: Need permission to access this file . requested you for access permission. Mail is er.sharmauttam@gmail.com @prasannaputtaswamy

Comment: check this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/zied8ojtsqw0d5r/f.rar?dl=0

Comment: thank you very much its working now. just replaced with your index.html and its working . Thanks @prasannaputtaswamy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after changing jquery version it works

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whether your answer is from a browser test or the actual app test, but you have to make sure you add the whitelist to your config.xml file

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: actually its a browser test.

Comment: great, have you imported JQuery itself, i am sure if you open the console it tells you where the problem is, snapshot your console log

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
index.html:24 Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at showRoom (index.html:24)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:33)
    at fire (jquery-1.11.0.js:3099)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.js:3211)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.js:3423)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.11.0.js:3453)

Comment: a screenshot also added in answer . please check it . Thanks

Comment: have you tried to use higher version of JQuery prerably 2.x

Comment: i personally have tried 3.x until i dowgraded to 2.x and its working, try to use v2.x

Comment: Tried with 2.x and 1.x too

Comment: you mind showing us where you are importing your JS scripts?

Comment: from jquery CDN